# Use page <title/> in surrounding template in Lift

Tags: lift

I know that in my `/page.html` I can do:

```
...
<body class="lift:content_id=main">
<div id="main" class="lift:surround?with=default;at=content">
  <title class="lift:head">TITLE_GOES_HERE</title>
...
```

... but it would be much more **transparent** for designers to be able to just put `<title/>` in the `<head/>` of a `/page.html`.

Would it be possible for a `<title/>` snippet used in `/templates-hidden/default.html` to somehow **read** the regular head `<title/>` in currently used `/page.html`?

Thanks!

Comment: I think it's better to propose changes on the official liftweb source to ask questions, that is on the mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/liftweb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is rather "no", because Lift reads only the data inside `id="???"` in `page.html`. This is an architecture choice AFAIK.

You should ask on the mailing list, I think, if you propose any changes to the Lift architecture.

BTW, do you know that the title is overridden (inserted) if you use the `SiteMap`?: https://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/liftweb/SiteMap

Comment: Ok, thank you, so I thought. It is overriden even if I use `SiteMap` without `<title class="lift:Menu.title"/>`?! ;O